# Quantum probability of entangled spin-1/2 particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Let us say that you have two entangled spin-1/2 particles (entangled in such a away that angular momentum is conserved). Let us say particle 1 moves to the left and particle 2 to the right. We measure the spin of particle 1 along the z-axis and find it to be $+$ say. If we then measure the spin of  particle 2 along an axis at an angle $\theta$ to the z-axis what is the probability that we also find the spin to be $+$?

Here are my thoughts.

- We know when $\theta=0$ the probability is $0$
- When $\theta=\pi$ the probability is $1$
- When $\theta=\pi/2$ the probability is $1/2$

From these the probablity seems to be of the form:
$$P(\theta)=cos^2(\theta/2)$$
But I am unsure and have no sources for this, is this correct, if so can you explain why and if not can you explain why?

Comment: I suggest Feynman lectures, part 8 (quantum mechanics I) - there is good discussion in the beginning of the book about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps illuminating to think in terms of polarisation-entangled photons, where this result is sometimes recognised as the *quantum Malus' law*. A reference can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9502028). As you will see from Eq. (3), this simply derives from transmission probability $\left|\mathcal{A}\right|^{2}=\left|\langle\Omega|\vec{a}'\rangle\right|^{2}$ (consistent with your intuition).

Spin entanglement is really no different. [This source](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/notes/chap4.pdf) in particular discusses the result in the context of spin (see Eq. (4.14)).

Comment: The experiments show that cos² is a good approximation but in general the fit is not perfect. Polarizers don't follow exactly the law around 0 and $\frac{\pi}2$.

Answer (score 0):

The question at hand has nothing to do with entangled states. You can just start with knowing that your initial state is $|\psi_0\rangle=|1\rangle$ (I assume you meant $|+\rangle=|+z\rangle$. The standard notation is $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ for $|+z\rangle$ and $|-z\rangle$, and $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ for $|+x\rangle$ and $|-x\rangle$) and asking what is the probability to measure it along an axis with $\theta$ relative to $z$ axis.
The projection operator on pure state which directed to $\hat{n}_{\theta}$ is - 
$$P_{\hat{n}}={\mathbb{I}+\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma} \over 2}$$
Because of azimuthal symmetry we can choose $\phi=0$ so that $\hat{n}_{\theta}=(\sin{\theta},0,\cos{\theta})$ (Even without this assumption the final result won't depend on $\phi$, it just simplifies the calculations)
$$P_{\hat{n}}={1 \over 2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} +{1 \over 2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & 0\end{pmatrix}+{1 \over 2} \begin{pmatrix} \cos{\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & -\cos{\theta} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos^2{\theta \over 2} & {1 \over 2}\sin{\theta} \\ {1 \over 2}\sin{\theta} & \sin^2{\theta \over 2} \end{pmatrix}$$
The density matrix of your state is -
$$\rho =  |1\rangle \langle 1 |=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
And the probability is - 
$$p=Tr[\rho P_{\hat{n}} ]=\sin^2{\theta \over 2}$$
This is the probability to measure $|+\hat{n}_{\theta}\rangle $ if the initial state is $|\psi_0\rangle=|1\rangle$ (of course, the probability to measure $|-\hat{n}_{\theta}\rangle $ is $\cos^2{\theta \over 2}$)